# Cleaning up short segments in dataset

Tags: algorithm, time-series, classification, data-cleaning

I am trying to create a set of dependent variables for my classification model, with 0 being False and 90 being True (in red) when the purple line is above and below certain limits as illustrated in the plot below. However, I am getting short segments that I find difficult to remove. Is there an algorithm that I can use to remove these segments?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to get rid of, the extra spike at the end or the gap in the middle. In any case, this kind of stuff is extremely sensitive to the data you are using. What works for one data set, may not work for another.

To remove the segments you basically have options as far as checking for segment length. IE: Segment length must be at least `X`.

As for filling in the gap, Same idea, but compare the ratio of the length of the first segment, the gap and the last segment. IE: If the total segment size is greater than `X%` of the gap size, the two segments are actually 1 segment.

Actually you could use the above to handle removing the segment two. If one segment is more than `X%` larger than the other and the gap is less than `Y%` of the smaller/larger/combined segment, then remove the smaller segment.